# How to extract random intercepts from mixed effects Tidymodels

Tags: r, lme4, tidymodels

I am trying to extract **random intercepts** from tidymodels using `lme4` and `multilevelmod`. I able to do this using lme4 below:

**Using R and lme4:**

```
library("tidyverse")
library("lme4")

# set up model
mod <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject),data=sleepstudy)

# create expanded df
expanded_df <- with(sleepstudy,
                    data.frame(
                      expand.grid(Subject=levels(Subject),
                                  Days=seq(min(Days),max(Days),length=51))))

# create predicted df with **random intercepts**
predicted_df <- data.frame(expanded_df,resp=predict(mod,newdata=expanded_df))

predicted_df 

# plot intercepts
ggplot(predicted_df,aes(x=Days,y=resp,colour=Subject))+
       geom_line()
```

[image]

**Using tidymodels:**

```
# example from
# https://github.com/tidymodels/multilevelmod
library("multilevelmod")
library("tidymodels")
library("tidyverse")
library("lme4")
#> Loading required package: parsnip
data(sleepstudy, package = "lme4")


# set engine to lme4
mixed_model_spec <- linear_reg() %>% set_engine("lmer")


# create model
mixed_model_fit_tidy <- 
  mixed_model_spec %>% 
  fit(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data = sleepstudy)


expanded_df_tidy <- with(sleepstudy,
                    data.frame(
                      expand.grid(Subject=levels(Subject),
                                  Days=seq(min(Days),max(Days),length=51))))



predicted_df_tidy <- data.frame(expanded_df_tidy,resp=predict(mixed_model_fit_tidy,new_data=expanded_df_tidy))


ggplot(predicted_df_tidy,aes(x=Days,y=.pred,colour=Subject))+
       geom_line()
```

[image]

Using the `predict()` function seems to gives only the fixed effect predictions.

**Is there a way to extract the random intercepts from tidymodels and multilevelmod?** I know the package is still in development so it might not be possible at this stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can work around this as follows:

```r
predicted_df_tidy <- mutate(expanded_df_tidy,
       .pred = predict(mixed_model_fit_tidy,
                       new_data=expanded_df_tidy, 
                       type = "raw", opts=list(re.form=NULL)))
```

- `bind_cols()` instead of `mutate()` might be useful in some circumstances?
- the issue is that `multilevelmod` [internally sets the default for prediction to re.form = NA](https://github.com/tidymodels/multilevelmod/blob/8d9a54736695ae76c2ec19f46f30b80de36a7e9b/R/linear_reg_data.R#L140-L158); the code above resets it to `re.form = NULL` (which is the `lme4` default, i.e. include all random effects in the prediction)

[image: prediction plot with random intercepts]

If you actually want the random intercepts (only) I guess you could `predicted_df_tidy %>%  filter(Days==0)`

PS If you want to be more 'tidy' about this I think you can use `purrr::cross_df()` in place of `expand.grid` and pipe the results directly to `mutate()` ...

Comment: ```purrr::cross_df()``` was a great suggestion! Looking into it, it looks like it might be getting depreciated for tidyr::expand_grid() https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/406

Comment: argh, I can't keep up with tidyverse.

Comment: Me neither! I held out this long on tidymodels, but I'm trying!